# How can I avoid duplicate code when I use sort() in JavaScript to put Ascending/Descending options (react)?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

For my sort, I will have three options 'Asc', 'Desc', and 'None'.
These values will be selected through a dropdown.
In the component, I use a switch statement to make it work.

```
switch (order) {
 case 'Asc':
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.values.sort((a, b) => a < b ? -1 : 1)
  });
  break;
 case 'Desc':
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.values.sort((a, b) => a < b ? 1 : -1)
  });
  break;
 default:
  // resetting the data
```

This works, but the code itself seems repetitive. I am not sure how I can refactor this.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the repetitive logic into a function and call that function in each iteration like this.

```
const sortValues = (d, type) => {
  d.values.sort((a, b) => type === 'asc' ? a-b : a+b)
}

switch (order) {
 case 'Asc':
  data.forEach((val) => sortValues(val, "asc"));
  break;
 case 'Desc':
  data.forEach((val) => sortValues(val, "desc"));
  break;
 default:
  // resetting the data
```

Comment: But this will produce the same results for Asc ad Desc

Comment: Yes missed it, added the conditional check there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below snippet, which rely on built in methods only without conditions.

```
data = [4, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2]

order = 'Asc'

switch(order) {
 case 'Asc':
  console.log(data.sort())
  break;
 case 'Desc':
  console.log(data.sort().reverse())
  break;
 default:
  console.log(data)
}
```

**Update**
For sorting with object property, please find this example

```
function sort(data, order, property){
if(order == 'Asc'){
return data.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[property] - b[property];
})
} else if(order == 'Desc'){
return data.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[property] - b[property];
})
}
}

fruits = [
    {
        name: "Apple",
        quantity: 30
    },
    {
        name: "Orange",
        quantity: 120
    },
    {
        name: "Mango",
        quantity: 25
    }
]

switch(order) {
 case 'Asc':
  console.log(sort(fruits, 'Asc', 'quantity'))
  break;
 case 'Desc':
  console.log(sort(fruits, 'Desc', 'quantity'))
  break;
 default:
  console.log(fruits)
}
```

Comment: Also you can use ```data.sort(function(a, b){return b-a})``` to avoid using revers() in Desc order.

Comment: Thanks, but what if we are sorting some object elements based on the key? `e.g. a.age, b.age`

Comment: @user6792790 Then you can have a check on age property i.e data.sort(function(a, b){return b.age-a.age})

Answer (score -1):

```
   switch (order) {
 case 'Asc':
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.values.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1) //For ascending order 
  });
  break;
 case 'Desc':
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.values.sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1) //For Descending order
  });
  break;
 default:
```